# How to make sure the command Add-MailboxFolderPermission executed successfully

Tags: powershell-2.0

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ayla@contoso.com:\Marketing -User ed@contoso.com -AccessRights Owner

I have executed the above command and the folder permissions added to the users successfully. But I am not sure how to check from script perspective the command executed successfully.

my requirement is to execute the command from powershell script and make-sure the users have added  successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ayla@contoso.com:\Marketing | Select -expand User

foreach ($user in $users)
{

```
Get-User $user.DisplayName | select Samaccountname
```

}

the above command should give you permissions on the particular folder

Comment: yes right, it displays the full details of the user(first name,last name) but i wanted userid information. since firstname,lastname i cant validate.

Comment: can you please explain me what parameters i need to pass to below command Get-User $user.DisplayName | select Samaccountname

Comment: You are passing the **User** column from Get-MailboxFolderPermission output

Comment: how to give access to sub-folders with the main folder in exchange server ? the below command only give access to only marketing folder not giving to inside the subfolders. Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ayla@contoso.com:\Marketing -User ed@contoso.com -AccessRights Owner